# $(this) returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit:
It appears that the wrong item was registering the mouseenter. So this question is solved I guess.

In the following code

```
$(".nav").mouseenter(function(){
     $('.'+$(this).attr("id")).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}, 800);
});
```

`$(this)` is returning `[object Object]` rather than the item the mouse has entered.
Edit:
After adding `confirm($(this));` as the last line inside of the .mouseenter function and hovering my mouse over one of those areas the dialog box says `[object Object]`. The Things with the id are to find the element with a class equal to the id of the object being moused over. I tested that bit of code on its own in the console and it worked perfectly. 
After running a console.log with $(this) it seems that $(this) is actually giving an output, but $(this).attr("id") is still not returning the ID.
Here is the html being affected:

```
<div id="body">
<span class="nav current" id="1">Home</span>
<span class="nav" id="2">Music</span>
<span class="nav" id="3">More</span>
</div>
<span class="nav background 1">Home</span>
<span class="nav background 2">Music</span>
<span class="nav background 3">More</span>
```

Comment: What is `this`? Could it be that the id is undefined?

Comment: `$(this)` is undefined or `id` is undefined? SHow html...we can't guess what problem is without markup

Comment: That's the beauty of chaining functions....it makes debugging a bitch.

Comment: You are telling jquery to find an element in the dom that has `class` which matches the `id` of the element that the mouse has just entered... Is that what you *intended* to tell the computer to do?

Comment: @32bitkid why did I read that in Tim Brooke-Taylor's voice? *"I'm now telling the computer exactly what it can do with a lifetime supply of chocolate"*

Comment: Don't use `alert` or `confirm` for debugging, they are too limited in their data output capabilities. Use `console.log` or your browser's JavaScript debugger instead.

Comment: @32bitkid Yes, it is.

Comment: @zzomtceo please provide a demo in jsfiddle.net with html that replicates issue. You haven't provided any html, and seem confused what `this` is. We don't have crystal balls to see what's happening

Comment: code works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/hnt3P/ Don't understand why you use same class for content blocks, but based on html and js given...`this` works fine

Answer (score 2):

$(this) is actually the object that triggered the function call.

Correct code:

```
$(".nav").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}, 800);
});
```

Comment: But `$(this)` is still equal to `[object Object]`

Comment: @zzomtceo of course it will...it's a jQuery object. And that is far different than undefined

Comment: @charlietfl Yes but it should return the specific object that is being moused over.

Comment: and that's what it is. You haven't provided any reason to believe it's not

Comment: @zzomtceo `this` -- or even `arguments[0].currentTarget` in your case -- is the *actual* DOM element that is presently handling the event (which *may not* be the reference to the element that is *actually* being hovered over, see event bubbling and the distinction between `event.target` and `event.currentTarget`). `$(this)` is wrapping that element in a jquery object/wrapper, which provides the `attr()` helper...

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your event handler depends on an element having an ID, I would make the initial selector a little more robust. Also, there's no need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object so I'd remove that too...

```
// only find .nav elements that also have an "id" attribute
$('.nav[id]').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    // here, `this` is the .nav element that has received a `mouseenter` event
    var selector = '.' + this.id;
    $(selector).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 800);
});
```